# SwiftUI: How to initialize a new StateObject in a parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observableobject, environmentobject

I have an app architecture similar to the below (simplified) code.  I use a `WorkoutManager` `StateObject` which I initialize in the set up view, then pass down to its children via `EnvironmentObject`.  The problem is that upon dismissing the `.sheet` there isn't any life cycle event which initializes a new `WorkoutManager`, which I need in order to be able to start new workouts consecutively. How in this example below can I give `WorkoutView` the ability to reinitialize WorkoutManager so that it is a clean object?

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

class WorkoutManager: ObservableObject {
    
    var workout: HKWorkout?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var workoutManager = WorkoutManager()
    
    @State var showingWorkoutView = false
    
    var body: some View {
      
        Button {
            showingWorkoutView.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Start Workout")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingWorkoutView) {
            WorkoutView(showingWorkoutView: $showingWorkoutView)
        }
        
    }
}

struct WorkoutView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager:  WorkoutManager
    @Binding var showingWorkoutView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Workout Started")
            .padding()
        Button {
            showingWorkoutView.toggle()
            //Here I want to initialize a new WorkoutManager to clear out the previous workout's state, how? 
        } label: {
            Text("End Workout")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Dumb question, but can't you create a method inside WorkoutManager to reset it's state without creating a new instance?

Comment: @Pastre not dumb at all but yes, my current solution right now is I have a resetWorkoutManager function inside workout manager which sets all of it's variables back to their initialized state.  Just feels a little hacky and I wondered if there was a more SwiftUI way to do this.

Comment: @GarySabo a reset state func doesn't seem hacky at all to me

Comment: @GarySabo "which sets all of its variables back in their initialized state" -- rather than setting all the variables, why not encapsulate the state in one `struct` that can be reset on the `WorkoutManager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, the route you probably want to take is reseting the state within the same `WorkoutManager`. You wouldn't be able to assign a *new* object to a `@StateObject` anyway -- you'll end up with compiler errors because of the `View`'s immutable `self`.

Secondly, I'd suggest that you probably don't want to rely on the `Button` in your `WorkoutView` to do this. For example, if the user dismissed the `sheet` by swiping, that wouldn't get called. Instead, you could listen for the `sheet`'s state in `onChange` (another method would be using the `onDismiss` parameter of `sheet`):

```
class WorkoutManager: ObservableObject {
    var workout: HKWorkout?
    
    func resetState() {
        //do whatever you need to do to reset the state
        print("Reset state")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var workoutManager = WorkoutManager()
    
    @State var showingWorkoutView = false
    
    var body: some View {
      
        Button {
            showingWorkoutView.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Start Workout")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingWorkoutView) {
            WorkoutView(showingWorkoutView: $showingWorkoutView)
        }
        .onChange(of: showingWorkoutView) { newValue in
            if !newValue {
                workoutManager.resetState()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WorkoutView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager:  WorkoutManager
    @Binding var showingWorkoutView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Workout Started")
            .padding()
        Button {
            showingWorkoutView.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("End Workout")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I should have clarified this is a WatchOS app so there isn't a way to dismiss the sheet other than the button.